# Installing CyanogenMod on Newsmy NP-711 tablet

Tags: cyanogenmod, hardware-requirements

I have a [Newsmy NP-711](http://gdgt.com/newsmy/newpad/np711/) Android 2.1 tablet (terrible device, cannot recommend it to anyone), and I would like to install CyanogenMod on it.

On their page, they only have downloads for specific phone and tablet models. Is there no "minimum-build" that might work for non-listed devices? And how would I go about installing it?

Comment: Each build has drivers and other configuration elements specific to the device it targets, so I think the best you can really do would be to find a supported device that has similar hardware and pray (or port it yourself). That's my understanding, anyway.

Comment: Any ideas what might be similar enough?

Comment: I haven't a clue, really. I don't know anything about that device and I don't see a detailed spec sheet readily available.

Answer (score 4):

Nope.  Mobile device drivers tend to be highly specific and there's no sort of defaults that will work across devices.